# How do I document a Python function returning a Numpy array of a known size?

Tags: python, numpy, documentation, typing

I would like to know how I can document a function that returns a numpy array of a known size.

I have a function declared like

```py
def poseToVector6(pose: Pose) -> np.ndarray:
```

The function returns a numpy array of a known size, namely a 6x1 column vector, given the semantics of the output.

I would like to know how I can specify the shape of the returned array.

If I change the declaration to

```py
def poseToVector6(pose: Pose) -> np.ndarray((6,1)):
```

then, when importing the function from an external module, VSCode suggests the function's signature to be

```py
(function) def poseToVector6(pose: Pose) -> Any
```

instead of

```py
(function) def poseToVector6(pose: Pose) -> ndarray
```

Is there a way to write a more accurate documentation?

Answer (score 1):

To accurately document the function that returns a numpy array of a known size, you can use type hints and docstrings in Python

```
def poseToVector6(pose: Pose) -> ndarray:
    """
    Convert a pose to a 6x1 column vector.

    Args:
        pose (Pose): The input pose.

    Returns:
        ndarray: A 6x1 column vector representing the pose.
    """
    # Implementation code here
    # ...

    
    return np.zeros((6, 1))
```

Comment: You can avoid specifying the type of an argument in the the docstring if you are already using type hints, like in your case.

Answer (score 0):

The size of an array is part of the *value*, not the type. What you want is the typical example used to demonstrate *dependent types*, which are not currently supported by `mypy` (or any other static type checker) AFAIK.

For documentary purposes, you can use `typing.Annotated` to attached size information.

```
from typing import Annotated


def poseToVector6(pose: Pose) -> Annotated[np.ndarray, (6, 1)]:
    ...
```

A specialized type checker could attempt to statically infer the size of the returned value to actually *check* against the annotated type, but as the size is a property of the *value*, not the type of the value, doing so is nontrivial if not impossible.